# Docker-compose command not displaying URL for project

Tags: docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to implement a github project based on electronic medical records but I am facing issue on last step while executing docker "docker compose up -d" in dir. Downloads/EHR/explorer where docker compose is residing the issue is this file is executing successfully but its not displaying any server URL for accessing project's front-end.
attach is the link to project.

Command error:
[image: command error]

https://github.com/Zzocker/EHR-on-blockchain

Answer (score 0):

As per [these lines of code](https://github.com/Zzocker/EHR-on-blockchain/blob/main/explorer/docker-compose.yaml#L53-L54), your app should be accessible at http://localhost:8080

> If you are not able to see anything, this means containers went down and you can check that by running `docker compose ps -a` & check the status of each container.

Comment: got this while running command. Unknown shorthand flag 'a' in -a. can you guide further